# Do I really need recursive chmod to restrict access to a folder?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

If I want to restrict access to a folder `secret` on a shared machine, do I really need recursive `chmod` on the folder

```bsh
chmod -R g=,o= secret
```

or is `chmod` on the folder sufficient?

```bsh
chmod g=,o= secret
```

What's the practical difference?

Comment: The premise of the question is a bit shaky.  The purpose of setting files' and directories' modes is to specify who should have what kind of access to them.  This is at least notionally a characteristic of each individual file and directory itself, independent of path, and each one should therefore have the appropriate mode assigned to it.  If you happen to make those decisions based on the structure of your directory tree, that does not any less mean that each individual file and directory should have the correct mode assigned to it.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

For a directory, "read" access lets you list the contents, and "execute" access lets your traverse the directory to open one of its children (file or subdirectory). So if you remove:

- just the read access, people can still access subdirectories by guessing their names
- just the execute flag, people can still list the names of the contents even if they cannot access them, and this can still be revealing
- both read and execute privileges on a directory, anything below it becomes unreachable, and you don't need to make a recursive change.

Of course if you make a recursive change, an accidental non-recursive reset of the access rights to the top directory will have less consequences.

Comment: So, a short answer to the title question would be "no, you don't, just `chmod`'ing the top level folder is sufficient"?

Comment: Yes, for all future accesses.

Answer (score 46):

It goes without saying that,
if you created a file two days ago (with a publicly readable mode),
and somebody read the file yesterday, or made a copy of it,
then there’s nothing you can do today to make that file private.

[xenoid says](https://superuser.com/q/1425574/354511#1425631) (somewhat simplistically) that,
if you remove group and other permission from your directory (today, now),
“anything below it becomes unreachable,
and you don't need to make a recursive change.” 
I agree that, if you `chmod` your (top-level) directory appropriately,
nobody but yourself<sup>1</sup>
will be able to get into it in the future (i.e., from now on). 
But there are some gotchas.

#### Hard links

Remember that file you created two days ago? 
Suppose that your adversary made a hard link to that file yesterday
(instead of copying it).
If you `chmod` only your (top-level) directory,
then that file will continue to have the publicly readable permissions
you assigned when you created it,
and so the bad guy will still be able to read it in the future
— (potentially) even if you subsequently modify it. 
If you do a recursive `chmod`,
that will secure the permissions on the file,
*which will affect the link.* 
The bad guy will still be able to do `ls -l` on it,
so they’ll be able to see when you change it, and how big it is,
but they won’t be able to read it again.

#### Working directory

Suppose that, under your `secret` directory,
you have a `plans` directory, and it also is publicly readable. 
And suppose that, five minutes ago,
the bad guy opened a terminal window and said

```
cd /home/clemisch/secret/plans
```

Now, after you do the `chmod` on `secret`,
the bad guy’s working directory is still  `/home/clemisch/secret/plans`,
and they can continue to list that directory and access the files there,
potentially forever. 
Of course, once they `cd` elsewhere, or close that window,
or log out, or the machine is rebooted, then they lose access.

If you do a recursive `chmod`, that will secure the permissions
on all the files and all the directories,
causing the squatter to lose access immediately.

This might not be a very big risk if the machine is a personal computer
that is accessed only through the console. 
But, if the bad guy might have left a `screen` or `tmux` session
in the background, then they could use this attack. 
And, if the machine supports `ssh`
(or other remote access; maybe even FTP would be enough),
this attack can be used.

#### Human error

As xenoid pointed out in their answer:
If you do a recursive `chmod` on `secret` today,
and then the day after tomorrow you accidentally
`chmod` (only) the top-level directory back to 755,
then you will still be protected by today’s recursive `chmod` —
all the files and directories under `secret` will still be unreadable. 
(Of course, if you create a *new* file in `secret` tomorrow,
and you allow it to be publicly readable, then it will be exposed
when you open the permissions on the `secret` directory. 
But that would be true
no matter whether today’s `chmod` was recursive or not.)

mazunki made [a comment](https://superuser.com/q/1425574/354511#comment2151201_1425578), “I believe `cp` carries permissions.” 
I’m not sure what they meant, but consider this scenario. 
You want to do a `diff` between two files:

- `secret/plans/the/quick/brown/fox/file1`
- `secret/jumps/over/the/lazy/dog/file2`

But you aren’t sure exactly where those files are,
and you have to poke around to find them. 
You might be tempted to do

```
cd plans
cd the/quick                            # looking for file1
cd brown/fox                            # found it!
cp file1 /tmp
cd ../../../../..
cd jumps/over
cd the                                  # looking for file2
cd lazy/dog                             # found it!
diff /tmp/file1 file2
```

If you do this, then `/tmp/file1` will have the same protection
as `secret/plans/the/quick/brown/fox/file1` —
so that’s another reason to do the recursive `chmod` today.

#### ONE more thing

If the bad guy opened one of your secret files five minutes ago,
and keeps it open, they will be able to read it in the future
— *potentially* even if you modify it. 
The good news is that this is a somewhat tricky attack to execute —
the bad guy has to have put some thought into it, before you do the `chmod`. 
The bad news is that this attack is very difficult to defend against
— a recursive chmod won’t help.
__________
<sup>1</sup> and, of course, privileged users / processes

P.S. You can shorten your command a little:
`chmod go=` is equivalent to `chmod g=,o=`. 
(That won’t make the recursive `chmod` any faster, of course.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I will still keep xenoid's answer "accepted" because it's so concise, but the info about hard links and working directories is very interesting!

Comment: Hmmm. when you copy a file, you are the owner of the copy... and you can change the flags to your heart's desire.

Comment: The hardlink part is interesting. Would it be possible for someone to guess the inode number and create a hardlink even after the directory rights were changed?

Comment: @xenoid: Yes, of course.  I didn’t say “If you copy your file to ``/Users/Public``, you’ll have a problem”, because I would expect that the user wouldn’t copy a file from their `secret` directory to ```/Users/Public``` unless they intended to make it public.  My point is that, when you’re dealing with two things, you sometimes use a third place.  If you have a chair and a table, and you want to swap them (i.e., move them to each other’s locations), you’ll drag one of them into the middle of the room, move the second one to where the first one was, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and then move the first one (from the middle of the room) to where the second one was. It’s a *temporary* location; you don’t think about how inconvenient a chair in the middle of the room might be, because you’re only going to have it there for a minute.  Likewise, somebody might copy a file to `/tmp` ***temporarily*** for convenience, without thinking about the security implications.  Besides, even if you do `chmod go= /tmp/file1` after you do `cp file1 /tmp`, you have created a window of opportunity during which the file was publicly readable.

Comment: @allo: Good question. I’m pretty sure that there is no program or system call that lets you create a link just by knowing the inode number.  If a user had full access to the disk (i.e., read/write access to `/dev/sda1`, or whatever), they could probably create such a link with a hex editor or a filesystem editor (like [debugfs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/debugfs.8.html)).  But that’s moot; anybody who has full read access to the disk can read any file; that’s why that access is typically given only to root (and possibly some other system services).

Comment: The [syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) takes two paths and the directory filedescriptors. I guess the paths are not checked for permissions, but you probably cannot get a valid file descriptor on the parent directory, when you have insufficient rights.

Comment: @allo: The `link` syscall is, of course, the standard hard-link function that has existed in Unix since the 1970s (predating symbolic links).  The `ln` program is basically just a wrapper for the `link` syscall. Now the `linkat` syscall is somewhat newer, and maybe hasn’t been tested quite as thoroughly as its uncle.  I’ve never used it.  It would be interesting to see how that could be applied to this problem; especially in coordination with an attack where the bad guy opened your directory before you did the chmod.

Answer (score -1):

Recursive `chmod` affects all subdirectories and folders too, not just the folder itself.

```bsh
.:
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  4 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 35 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:42 ..
d---------  3 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:46 a
d---------  2 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:42 b

./a:
total 12
d--------- 3 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:46 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:42 ..
-----w---- 1 mazunki mazunki    0 april 15 11:42 a
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 april 15 11:46 aa
-----w---- 1 mazunki mazunki    0 april 15 11:42 b

./a/aa:
total 8
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 april 15 11:46 .
d--------- 3 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:46 ..

./b:
total 8
d--------- 2 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:42 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:42 ..
-----w---- 1 mazunki mazunki    0 april 15 11:42 a
-----w---- 1 mazunki mazunki    0 april 15 11:42 b
[] ~:~/test ▶ 
[] ~:~/test ▶ 
[] ~:~/test ▶ sudo chmod -R +w a
[] ~:~/test ▶ 
[] ~:~/test ▶ 
[] ~:~/test ▶ sudo ls -alR 
.:
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  4 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 35 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:42 ..
d-w-------  3 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:46 a
d---------  2 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:42 b

./a:
total 12
d-w------- 3 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:46 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:42 ..
--w--w---- 1 mazunki mazunki    0 april 15 11:42 a
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 april 15 11:46 aa
--w--w---- 1 mazunki mazunki    0 april 15 11:42 b

./a/aa:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 april 15 11:46 .
d-w------- 3 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:46 ..

./b:
total 8
d--------- 2 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:42 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:42 ..
-----w---- 1 mazunki mazunki    0 april 15 11:42 a
-----w---- 1 mazunki mazunki    0 april 15 11:42 b
```

If you don't explicitly give access to `.`, you won't be able to read the contents of the folder.

```
[] ~:~/test ▶ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:46 a
d--------- 2 mazunki mazunki 4096 april 15 11:42 b
[] ~:~/test ▶ 
[] ~:~/test ▶ 
[] ~:~/test ▶ sudo chmod +xxx b
[] ~:~/test ▶ cd b
[] ~:~/test/b ▶ ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
[] ~:~/test/b ▶ sudo chmod +xxx .
[] ~:~/test/b ▶ ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
[] ~:~/test/b ▶ sudo chmod +rrr .
[] ~:~/test/b ▶ ls
a  b
[] ~:~/test/b ▶
```

Likewise, you won't be able to `cd` into subdirectories of said folder unless you explicitly `+x` them.

Comment: I think the OP understands what "recursive" means. What's your answer to the title question? (yes or no?) What about "*practical* difference"?

Comment: Sorry, what you wrote may all be true but I don't see how it answers the question. I think the question can be rephrased: after `chmod g=,o= secret/`, do permissions of objects inside `secret/` matter? Well, do they?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I still don't see a difference concerning the secrecy of the folder though. Could it be that you could still `cd` into a *specific* subfolder if you knew the path *beforehand*?

Comment: I just tested that and it does not seem to work. Then I really don't see any difference. As `-R` takes much longer (of course) for many files, I will stick to normal `chmod` I guess.

Comment: If it matters, I believe `cp` carries permissions.

Comment: Really the OP wants to know if someone can go deep without having access to ancestor folders, jumping over the 600's say.

Comment: I agree with @KamilMaciorowski — you don’t seem to be saying anything wrong, but it’s not clear what you are saying. Your example is long and confusing, and you muddy the waters with your use of ```sudo``` and directories with mode 0.