# Changing user password for multiple server using shell script, Linux Debian10

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

I have a few servers I need to configure and all the servers have the same user, I need to have the user to key in the username and new password so that I can run this script to configure all servers. This is the error I am currently facing, and sorry I am new to Linux scripting please help me out, Thank you!

```
$ cat serverlist.txt
192.168.1.8
192.168.1.7
192.168.1.6
```

```
$ cat changepasswd.sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter username: " username
read -p "Enter new password: " new_password
for server in 'cat serverlist.txt'
do echo -e "Server IP is: $server"
ssh $server 'echo "new_password\nnew_password" | passwd username
done
```

```
$ chmod 777 changepasswd.sh

$ sh changepasswd.sh
Enter username: vncuser
Enter new password: abc12345
changepasswd.sh: 9: changepasswd.sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Comment: Like the error says, there is an unterminated quoted string. The unpaired single-quote (`'`) is between `$server` and `echo`. Not an answer because after you fix this, you will encounter more problems. There is more to fix in the script; but even `chmod` and `sh` are disputable.

Comment: Apart from what Kamil already mentioned, you would want to fix your `'cat serverlist.txt'`, backticks in place of single quotes. The single quotes won't execute the cat command.

Answer (score 2):

Like the error says, there is an unterminated quoted string. The unpaired single-quote (`'`) is between `$server` and `echo`. If you only fix it like this

```
ssh $server 'echo "new_password\nnew_password" | passwd username'
```

you will encounter more problems.

---

Problems I noticed (starting from general ones, not necessarily most severe):

0. You used a shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) but then called the script by `sh changepasswd.sh`. In this case the shebang is totally ignored and the interpreter is `sh`. Usually it's better to rely on the shebang and run a script as `./the_script`; this way the caller does not need to wonder which interpreter to use, the right interpreter is in the shebang.
1. You made the script executable (with `chmod`) but `sh changepasswd.sh` does not need it to be executable. On the other hand calling with `./changepasswd.sh` would need it to be executable.
2. You used `sh` as the interpreter, but `read -p` is not portable. Your `sh` may support it, other implementations may or may not. Using `bash` will allow you not only to use `-p` reliably, but also `-s` (for not echoing the password). One way or another you should use [`-r` and `IFS=''` (empty string)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/108618) especially when reading a password. In Bash see `help read` to learn what these options do.
3. If you decide to use the shebang, it's better to get rid of the `.sh` suffix. If you ever port the script to another interpreter (or even compile a binary executable), the name `changepasswd` will still fit, while `changepasswd.sh` would need to be changed or it would be confusing.
4. `chmod 777` makes the script writable for anyone. If the script is in a directory where other users [have certain rights](https://superuser.com/a/1425631/432690), they will be able to change the script. E.g. they can inject a line that will send/store `$new_password` for them. `744` may be the right mode.
5. It's advisable to ask for a new password twice and abort if the two strings don't match.
6. `for server in 'cat serverlist.txt'` will assign `cat serverlist.txt` (string) to the variable. You meant `` `cat serverlist.txt` `` or `$(cat serverlist.txt)`. The latter [is better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5782/108618).
7. *In general* [you should double-quote `$( )`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) to prevent word splitting and filename generation; but in this case you do want word splitting (yet you don't want filename generation). Looping over the lines of a file (`serverlist.txt` in your case) can be done with `read` (but [there are pitfalls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107800/108618)). However if your file contains IP addresses or simple hostnames only then `for server in $(cat serverlist.txt)` seems fine. Just remember [it's not a good general way](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).
8. Still you should double-quote variables like `$server`.
9. `"new_password\nnew_password"` is just a string. You want to expand variables: `"$new_password\n$new_password"`. In general, when concatenating, you may want to use [`${new_password}`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396162/108618).
10. The "fixed" snippet

    ```
     ssh $server 'echo "$new_password\n$new_password" | passwd $username'
    ```

will not expand `$new_password` nor `$username` locally, because [these are single-quoted](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690). The remote shell will expand them (most likely to empty strings). To expand locally, the variables should be double-quoted:

```
    ssh "$server" "echo '$new_password\n$new_password' | passwd '$username'"
```

But this is still error prone, keep reading.

0. The SSH server will get the entire command string as a string. A remote shell will interpret it. This means a single-quote character in (locally expanded) `$new_password` (or `$username`) will break the code. This way you can even inject code. It's not about possible code injection (I understand you can execute any code anyway); it's about setting an unexpected password. There are few ways to deal with this:

- In general you can tell `ssh` to pass some variables to the remote side, if the server allows it. Then a remote shell could expand them safely. This depends on the server configuration; plus on the client side it's hard (and not elegant) to define the variables for `ssh` dynamically. You shouldn't do this in this case, but if you want to learn more then  investigate `PermitUserEnvironment` in `man 5 sshd_config`.
- Bash allows you to expand a variable in a special way, so after the result is parsed in a shell, it becomes the original string again. This is done with `${variable@Q}`. The expanded string is properly quoted and/or escaped.
- Since you're reading from a pipe on the remote side, you can pipe to `ssh` locally and avoid passing (locally expanded) `$new_password` as a string that is about to be parsed.

Whatever you choose, remember you need to properly quote for the local shell and *separately* for the remote shell (in case of `${variable@Q}` the local `Q` operator handles this part).

0. Do not use `echo` to pass "random" strings, [prefer `printf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618). If you decide to pipe a variable to `ssh` in Bash, then a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) may be a good way. In your case you need to pass `$new_password` twice (plus newlines), so I would go with `printf` anyway.

---

The script may look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS= read -rp "Enter username: " username
IFS= read -rsp "Enter new password: " new_password
echo    # just to get a newline
IFS= read -rsp "Repeat new password: " new_password_2
echo
[ "$new_password" = "$new_password_2" ] || { echo "Mismatch. Aborting."; exit 1; }
for server in $(cat serverlist.txt)
   do echo "Server IP is: $server"
   printf '%s\n' "$new_password" "$new_password" | ssh "$server" "passwd -- ${username@Q}"
done
```

You need to make it executable (`chmod u+x changepasswd`) and run it with `./changepasswd`.

Notes:

- The script assumes no `passwd` will ask for the current password. This assumption originates in the script you published.
- The script assumes all remote `passwd` support [double dash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/108618).
- `ssh "$server" "passwd -- ${username@Q}"` could be `ssh "$server" "passwd '$username'"`, if you're sure expanded `$username` is [safe](https://serverfault.com/a/578264). Basic validation can be done locally.