# Capture traffic on specific SFTP Port

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, port, logging, sftp

I have configured my SFTP server to run on the default SSH port 22 and another port (X). I want to monitor the traffic on my server in the default port to check if anyone is still using port 22.

I have tried checking the logs in var/log, but they do not show which port the user is being used.
Just to be clear, my only requirement is to get all the users trying to connect to port 22.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

#### Preliminary note

You mentioned `var/log` (did you mean `/var/log`?), so I guess your OS is Linux. I assume you're using OpenSSH.

---

#### Bogo-solution

> my only requirement is to get all the users trying to connect to port 22.

Disable the port and see who complains. :D

---

#### Simple solution

A simple solution is to increase the `LogLevel` from the default `INFO` to `VERBOSE` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
LogLevel VERBOSE
```

<sup>Remember [the first obtained value will be used](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config).</sup>

Reload `sshd` (in my Debian: `systemctl reload sshd.service`). From now on `sshd` will send more information to the syslogd (in my Debian: `rsyslogd`). It depends on the configuration of the syslogd (in my Debian: `/etc/rsyslog.conf`) where this information gets ultimately written to (in my Debian: `/var/log/auth.log`).

From now on, lines like

```
… sshd[…]: Connection from … port … on … port …
```

will appear. In your case the latter port will be `22` or X. Unfortunately, to tell if the connection successfully authenticated, as what user, and if it used SFTP, you'll need to analyze lines that follow. These lines won't contain the port. A sane filter is

```
grep -F ' sshd[' /var/log/auth.log
```

to filter out lines not related to `sshd`, but it's not a trivial task to filter this further.

---

#### Simple improvement? No

If you are interested in SFTP users only, then you'd like logs from the SFTP server better, not all logs from the entire SSH server. In your `sshd_config` there's a line like

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

or

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/sftp-server
```

Both `internal-sftp` and `sftp-server` can be configured to be verbose by appending `-l VERBOSE`, but even then they won't show you the port you're interested in.

---

#### Advanced solution

Alternatively create a wrapper over `sftp-server` that will log what you want. Like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/logger -p auth.info "SFTP connected: $SSH_CONNECTION"
exec /usr/lib/sftp-server "$@"
```

Name it `sftp-server-wrapper`. It should be owned by root and its mode should be `755`. Place it in a directory any SFTP user can reach ([mind directory permissions](https://superuser.com/a/1425631/432690)).

Now tell your `sshd` to use the wrapper instead of `sftp-server` or `internal-sftp`. In `sshd_config` find the `Subsystem sftp …` line and make it:

```
Subsystem sftp /path/to/sftp-server-wrapper
```

where `/path/to/` is the right path. Reload `sshd`.

From now on any *successful* connection that requests `sftp` subsystem will log its parameters. The port you want to know will be at the very end. Useful filter:

```
grep 'SFTP connected: ' /var/log/auth.log
```

or even:

```
grep 'SFTP connected: .* 22$' /var/log/auth.log
```

Notes:

- This method cannot use `internal-sftp`.
- SSH users that don't request the `sftp` subsystem will not be logged.