# Make symlink contents available to users from group

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I have a directory `/data` which belongs to the `tct-data` group. I also have an external drive connected through the USB mounted in `/media/tct/external_drive`. I want to create a symlink inside `/data` pointing to `/media/tct/external_drive/somewhere/in/the/drive` and that all users from the `tct-data` group can follow this link and work normally there. I tried `ln -s /media/tct/external_drive/somewhere/in/the/drive /data/work_here` but then other users still cannot access. I also set `chown :tct-data -R /media/tct/external_drive/somewhere/in/the/drive` and still other users cannot access it. How can I do this?

Comment: (1) [One inaccessible directory in the path is enough to block access](https://superuser.com/q/1425574/432690), a symlink does not circumvent this. (2) Is FUSE involved? What is the output of `mount | grep /media/tct/external_drive`?

Comment: About (2), I don't know about FUSE, the output of your command gives this `/dev/sda1 on /media/tct/external_drive (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,stripe=8191,uhelper=udisks2)`

Comment: Are you sure there is no `type something` in this output?

Comment: I copy-pasted the output here.